# Sign of Lagrangian constraint function in rotations

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, conventions

How can I foolproof decide the correct sign of the constraint function in Lagrangian mechanics, particularly in rotations?

In a simple example, lets consider a cylinder rotating around its main axis in positive direction. Accelerating the cylinder further in positive direction with constant $\dot{\omega}$ requires a torque. The Lagrangian would be:

$$
L=\frac{1}{2} I \omega^2
$$

The angle of rotation $\Omega$ would be

$$
\Omega = \frac{1}{2} \dot{\omega}t^2 + C_1 t + C_2
$$

Then I think I have two options for the constraint functions

$$
\eta_1 = \Omega - (\frac{1}{2} \dot{\omega}t^2 + C_1 t + C_2) = 0  \quad\text{or}\tag{1}
$$
$$
\eta_2 = -\Omega + (\frac{1}{2} \dot{\omega}t^2 + C_1 t + C_2) = 0   \tag{2}
$$

My Euler-Lagrange equation becomes

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \omega} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \Omega} + \tau \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial \Omega}
$$

Using $\eta_1$ gives the correct torque $\tau = I \dot{\omega}$, while $\eta_2$ gives the wrong sign for the torque.

In this simple example, the direction of the torque is obvious, but in problems with several rotation bodies interacting with each other, the direction of the torque might not be so obvious.

Comment: You should be able to get the correct answers with either choice of sign. The dynamics will set the sign when you finally solve for the results. If you pick wrongly you will just get a negative result.

Comment: Exactly, I would get the opposite sign. It matters, because in an actual system it would mean that I need to change from generator to motor, which makes a big difference in energy flow.

Comment: no, if you assumed a generator and the answer is a motor, the solution will tell you it is a motor.

Comment: That's what I would expect, too. However, in my example the sign of the torque seems to depend solely on the choice of the sign of my constraint function. I am assuming that the choice of the constraint function is linked to an assumed direction of the torque. But I am not seeing it.